# jquery datepicker in ajax form not editable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am using datepicker in a jquery dialog box. It works fine while adding values but while editing it is not accepting new values

Here is my code

```
  var edtdlg = $("#editDialog").html(html);

                $(".dob", edtdlg).datepicker({
                    dateFormat : "dd MM yy",
                    changeMonth : true,
                    changeYear : true
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit form was actually a jsrender template hence i needed to add a seperate datepicker once the template was compiled in the edit() function.

The data being selected in edit() functions date picker was being added to the global datepicker of the grid which was used by add() function. After  placing the global datepicker inside add() function it  is working fine:)